# How to append new columns with data from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know the title might seem confusing but the real situation is as follow: I have two tables with existing data and both of them have `n` rows but different columns. The order of the rows in two tables do match. So the goal is such that after appending, the first row of the second table is appended to the first row of the first table, etc. and all the columns from the second table are added to the first table - basically just like paste two tables together.

Comment: So if table 1 has 100 records and 5 columns, and table 2 has 100 records and 5 columns, you want table 3 to have 100 records and 10 columns?  Is there anything that is linking the two tables together, or is it linked by a wish and a prayer?

Comment: @franglais The description is correct. So if the two tables have no linkage this can't be done?

Comment: You have to have something in common between the two of them - you said "the order of the rows do match" - do you mean that both tables have IDs, and ID #1 in Table1 = ID #1 in Table2?

Comment: @AHiggins No, it's more like the first table has ID, FirstName and the second table has LastName, ExtraInfo

Comment: So, to clarify: there are absolutely no columns that the two tables have in common.  Still a bit confused by your assertion that the order matches - is there something you can consistently sort by that will always show them the same way? If so, you could apply a row number ...

Comment: If the tables are heaps (i.e. no clustered index) then the order is random and any match is fluke rather than by design.  If the tables DO have clustered indexes then the order when you do a SELECT * FROM will be by this index (it isn't guaranteed but in the real world it always will be) and so you can use this to join your tables together?